# Which branch of $f(x)$ use to find the limit?

Tags: calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function define by,

$$f(x)= \begin {cases} \frac{1}{1+x^2}&\text{if $x$ is rational}\\
\frac{1}{2x}\ &\text{if $x$ is irrational}\\
\end {cases}$$

Now, let $a$ be a rational number. What branch of $f$ should I use to find $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$?

If one had $g$ defined by,

$$g(x)= \begin {cases} \frac{1}{1+x^2}&\text{if $x=1$}\\
\frac{1}{2x}\ &\text{if $x \neq 1$}\\
\end {cases}$$

And if it were asked the $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}g(x)$, I would use the $2^{th}$ branch. But I don't have a clue about which branch to use to find  the $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If it exists, it does not matter which branch you choose...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the limit exists, it means for all sequences {$x_n$} that converge to **a**, the sequence {$f(x_n)$} converges to the limit. Now if we take $a=1$ and {$x_n$} to be a sequence of rational numbers that converge to $1$, {$f(x_n)$} converges to $0.5$ and same thing happens if we take {$x_n$} to be a sequence of irrational numbers that converge to $1$.So we can naively conclude that the limit **probably**(because we haven't yet checked sequences with both rationals and irrationals) exists.If we take $a=-1$ and {$x_n$}  be a sequence of rational numbers that converge to $-1$, {$f(x_n)$} converges to $0.5$ again but if we take {$(x_n)$} to be an irrational sequence converging to $-1$, {$f(x_n)$} converges to $-0.5$. So we can definitely say that the limit doesn't exist for $a=-1$.Same line of reasoning shows if the limit exists at some $a$, $a$ must satisfy $$1+a^2=2a\Rightarrow(a-1)^2=0\Rightarrow a=1$$.

Answer (score 1):

If the limit exists, then it should not make a difference which of these two you use. By that logic, we can informally see that the only value of $a$ where your limit exists is $1$.

Remember the definition of a limit, you want to ensure that for any epsilon bound, you can pick a corresponding delta interval where ALL the $x$ values satisfy the epsilon bound. This means that irrationals and rationals must be both considered (since they are both on the interval).

Comment: Do you really want to say "the only value of a where your limit exists is 1"

Answer (score 0):

they are two different functions. for the second case, $g(x)=\frac{1}{2x}$ being continue lets us find the limit. But for the first case, $f(x)$ is not a function bounded locally, so we can't find the limit.